# How to add a contact to Yahoo using Oauth-2 in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I've been wrestling with this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution. The closest I've come is PHP code for Oauth-1 by Joe Chung (https://github.com/joechung/oauth_yahoo), but I can't get my head wrapped around it.

I'm using Asp.Net, and this code is in the ContactController. I have no trouble Getting contacts from Yahoo. The problem is Adding a contact to a user's Yahoo address book. The program proceeds through the Yahoo login process, and there are no errors. But the contact is not saved. I hope someone can take a look at this and tell me what I'm missing.

Thanks.

```
private string AddYahooContact(string responseFromServer, string contactIdForYahoo)
    {
        // Some of this from http://www.yogihosting.com/implementing-yahoo-contact-reader-in-asp-net-and-csharp/
        responseFromServer = responseFromServer.Substring(1, responseFromServer.Length - 2);
        string accessToken = "", xoauthYahooGuid = "", refreshToken = "";
        string[] splitByComma = responseFromServer.Split(',');
        foreach (string value in splitByComma)
        {
            if (value.Contains("access_token"))
            {
                string[] accessTokenSplitByColon = value.Split(':');
                accessToken = accessTokenSplitByColon[1].Replace('"'.ToString(), "");
            }
            else if (value.Contains("xoauth_yahoo_guid"))
            {
                string[] xoauthYahooGuidSplitByColon = value.Split(':');
                xoauthYahooGuid = xoauthYahooGuidSplitByColon[1].Replace('"'.ToString(), "");
            }
            else if (value.Contains("refresh_token"))
            {
                string[] refreshTokenSplitByColon = value.Split(':');
                refreshToken = refreshTokenSplitByColon[1].Replace('"'.ToString(), "");
            }
        }
        // How to build contactUrl from https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts-xml_request_put
        // This is Yahoo's address to add a contact
        string contactUrl = "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/" + xoauthYahooGuid + "/contacts";            
        // Much of this from https://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(contactUrl);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // Tried "application/x-www-form-urlencoded & application/xml" & "text/xml".            
        // Create the data we want to send
        string yahooContact = BuildYahooContact(contactIdForYahoo);
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yahooContact);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }            
        responseFromServer = "";
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return yahooContact;
    }

    private string BuildYahooContact(string contactIdForYahoo)
    {
        Guid contactId = Guid.Parse(contactIdForYahoo);
        Models.Contact contact = GetContactForId(contactId);    // And find the contact           

        string firstName = "";
        string lastName = "";
        if (contact.FullName != null)
        {                
            int index = contact.FullName.IndexOf(" ");
            if (index > 0)
            {
                firstName = contact.FullName.Substring(0, index);
                lastName = (contact.FullName.Substring(index + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                lastName = contact.FullName;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.Append("<contact>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>name</type><value>");
        data.Append("<givenName>" + firstName + "</givenName><middleName/>");
        data.Append("<familyName>" + lastName + "</familyName>");
        data.Append("<prefix/><suffix/><givenNameSound/><familyNameSound/>");
        data.Append("</value></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>address</type>");
        data.Append("<value><street>" + contact.Address + "</street>");
        data.Append("<city>" + contact.City + "</city>");
        data.Append("<stateOrProvince>" + contact.State + "</stateOrProvince>");
        data.Append("<postalCode>" + contact.Zip + "</postalCode>");
        data.Append("<country>United States</country>");
        data.Append("<countryCode>US</countryCode>");
        data.Append("</value></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>notes</type><value>" + contact.Note + "</value></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>link</type><value>" + contact.Website + "</value></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>email</type><value>" + contact.Email + "</value></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>phone</type><value>" + contact.BusinessPhone + "</value><flags>WORK</flags></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>phone</type><value>" + contact.BestPhone + "</value><flags>MOBILE</flags></fields>");
        data.Append("<fields><type>phone</type><value>" + contact.SecondPhone + "</value><flags>PERSONAL</flags></fields>");
        data.Append("<categories><category><name>GoGoContract</name></category></categories>");
        data.Append("</contact>");

        return data.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you actually debug the code.. if you are using the `yahoo-api` do they have working examples within their documentation..?

Comment: I haven't found any working examples in the yahoo-api documentation. Yahoo doesn't allow for local-host, and Fiddler doesn't get past the Yahoo login. In other words, I don't know how to debug once it gets past the Yahoo login page.